# JUnit5 Test not loading properties from 'application-test.yml'

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit5

I am trying to write unit tests for my service class, which has dependency to a configuration properties class:

**MyService.java**

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyService {
  private final MyConfigProperties myConfigurationProperties;
}
```

**MyConfigProperties.java**

```
@ConfigurationProperties("prefix")
@Data
public class MyConfigProperties {
  int aValue;
  List<String> aList;
}
```

**application-test.yml**

```
prefix:
  aValue: 1
  aList: a, b, c
```

**MyServiceTest.java**

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyService.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = MyConfigProperties.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "spring.config.location=classpath:application-test.yml" })
class MyServiceTest {
  @Autowired
  MyService myservice;

  @Test
  void testSth(){
    //some test
  }
}
```

When I debug the test, I see that the myConfigurationProperties injected with default values such as aValue=0 and aList=null.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does it work if you use `@ActiveProfiles("test")` in `MyServiceTest`?

Comment: Same problem for me. I tried this also `@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.yml")`, but it is not loading. `@ActiveProfiles("test")` also not working.