# Spring JUnit5 test not loading resource values

Tags: java, spring, junit5

I know there are a lot of questions regarding this, but all of them are suggesting to use `@TestPropertySource` and `@EnableConfigurationProperties`. I have already used them but still not working.

**Config class** - `src/main/java/com/demo/config/AppConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "api")
@Getter
@Setter
public class AppConfig {
   private List<String> providers;
   private boolean enabled;
}
```

**Property source** - `src/test/resources/application-test.yml`

```
api:
  enabled: true
  providers:
    - prov1
    - prov2
```

**Test class** - `src/test/../MyTest.java`

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyTestConfiguration.class)
class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private AppConfig appConfig;

    @Test
    void runTest() {//some code with breakpoint}
}
```

**Test configuraton** - `src/test/.../MyTestConfiguration.java`

```
@TestConfiguration
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.yml")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = AppConfig.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class MyTestConfiguration {
}
```

When I run the test, `runTest()` and inspect autowired `appConfig` value, the `providers` are empty and `enabled` is `false`. That means the values in yml file were not loaded.
I found a [similar kind of question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68905139/junit5-test-not-loading-properties-from-application-test-yml), but without answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified `MyTest` as @sergey-tsypanov suggested and then deleted `MyTestConfiguration` class. It worked and `appConfig` has values.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = AppConfig.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private AppConfig appConfig;

    @Test
    void runTest() {//some code with breakpoint}
}
```

It seems even if I don't have `@SpringBootApplication`, I can use `@SpringBootTest` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration`. I had spring Boot dependency in pom.xml

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to replace

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyTestConfiguration.class)
```

with

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyTestConfiguration.class})
```

Then `application-test.yml` will be picked up automatically.

Comment: Thanks @sergey-tsypanov. But I got this error on running the test: `Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test`. But we put the second item, right. Still error.

Comment: @RamanujanR have you tried to replace `@Configuration` with `@SpringBootConfiguration` over `AppConfig`?

Comment: No. But I tried it now. Still same error. Please note that this is not  `SpringBootApplication`. But it have Spring dependency. This maven project supposed to build a jar file which is used in another project. I just want to make my tests work here.

Comment: But wait, you are using `@TestConfiguration` which is from `spring-boot-test` without having Spring Boot application. Let's replace then `@TestConfiguration` with plain `@Configuration`